# Create yii2 form fields according to database records

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

I am creating a project which is similar to `online exam system` where teachers create questions and answer type like `input` or `radio button` etc. I save those records in database and user logs in and see the form accordingly with appropriate input types.

How can i create those fields on the user form? My database is very simple like below

```
Questions       information
id              id
teacher_id      user_id 
subject_id      question_id
question        answer 
input_type
is_required
```

So i am stuck with a problem that how could i create those fields on the user view file? Should i only create one instance of `information` model and prints the fields with array? or should i create different instance of `information` model like below

```
foreach($modelInformation as $i=>$modelInformation){

   echo $form->field($modelInformation, "[{$i}]answer")->textInput();
}
```

Something like this? or there is some easy way to do this? I am confused because i am not sure how can i give validation if i go this way? Because some of the question can be optional and others are must to answer. If there are any example projects available for similar scenario than point it to me and i will work the rest. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this using the `html` helper. Assuming that you have defined relations between you `question` and information` models, you can create an active field, and pass the field type as a text parameter, like this.

```
echo Html::activeInput($modelInformation->question->input_type, $modelInformation, 'answer');
```

For validation, you will probably need to create a [standalone validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#standalone-validators) and use a switch statement to change the validation depending on the value of `$model->question->input_type`

Answer (score 0):

I think there is many way to create that project it depends what client wants or what  developer want to implement.
I can suggest to following way you can try this:

1. CMS model : try to make a admin panel in which all question will display 
   from database and you can select question 1 by one to define question should be objective , descriptive etc and that will generate the question on view form accordingly.
2. If your question's will fixed every time than make a view page and define which question should look like.according to you choice.But this will have to change every time if you change the question .
   So i would suggest try CMS pattern it will automate your project very well.